# Is there a way to change the color of my location's dot icon on google map in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using google map API in Android. Now I want to change the color of my location's dot icon on google map, from blue to purple. I've researched, but google map API doesn't support the way to change the color. Also I don't like to use a marker, because it doesn't have ripple effect. Yes, I just want to use the same dot icon (ripple effect and approximated distance circle), only change the color.
Is there any way to change to the color? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply not using default Marker icons and create your own instead.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to use default dot of google map.